# Mongo text search doesn't fetch results for keyword "How"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongo documents as follows,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b5ff3ec6df1fc21dc206d12"),
    "activityName" : "How sensor",
    "timeZone" : "+05.30",
    "venue" : "130 E San Fernando St #154, San Jose, CA 95112, USA",
    "activityState" : "Active",
    "activityType" : "campaign",
    "commentTheme" : "59c26fb3fd9a8e79242fe210",
    "commentEnabled" : false,
    "startTimeStamp" : 1532602800000.0,
    "endTimeStamp" : 2164186800000.0
}
```

And there is a text index created on filed `activityName` as follows,

```
`db.ActivityDetails.createIndex( { 'activityName':'text' } );`
```

But for the text search keyword `how` it doesn't output given document as results. Does anyone knows a possible reason for this behaviour. My query is as follows,

`db.getCollection('ActivityDetails').find({ $text: { $search: "how" } })`

but for the word `sensor`, it gives the correct results. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'how' is a [stop word in English](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt) It is ignored in text index and can't be searched.

You can experiment with `{default_language: 'none'}` which will not use any stop words, but it won't use steming either, so `sensor` won't match `sensors`.